# Building a CMS for bilingual website - need tips

Tags: php, web, content-management-system

I'm building a really simple CMS for a bilingual website. The website would have 5+5 pages each of which would have varying content. Its like you have an about us page, services page a news page and contact us page in two languages.

I was wondering that on the CMS backend admin panel I would be making .. what is the better option should I make two separate admin panels for the two different languages - it seems like over kill though but again what is the preferred way in such a case where you have a cms website in two different languages...

Or should I consider using a third party cms for this? I haven't worked in Drupal or in Jhoomla much and have little idea here. Basically my client needs a corporate website which would have an:

About us page, Mission Statement, Products[this should be updateable], News and Updates[updateable], Contact Us, Feedback etc to name a few.

The site should be bilingual as well.

How should I get on this I need to submit a mock up soon. I have about 10 days to finish the project so would like to hear some ideas on how to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep it inside one administrator's page. Just supply a list of languages somewhere on the page for a quick switch between them. So when admin is editing a page in English they choose Spanish and the English page is automatically saved and they go on editing the Spanish version.

The other thing you can do is use a tabbed wysiwyg editor like [Spaw2](http://www.spaweditor.com/) and put every language in it's own tab (since you will probably have only a couple of bilingual fields).

Comment: Nice idea however normally lets say for a page that doesn't have a translation. I would like that when people switch languages they be able to switch between translations but what is the normal procedure should a translation not be available for a page

Comment: In the admin panel you just show blank fields if translation is not available, and on the website depends on your content, but normally I would suggest putting content from the default language if translations are not available.

Answer (score 1):

Given the time constraint and the difficulty to write a CMS ( it's easy to write actually, but very hard to get it perfected, to do whatever you want to do), I suggest you using [Drupal](http://drupal.org).

Here's [a pointer](http://drupal.org/handbook/modules/locale) on how to do multi-language support in Drupal. The idea is that you specify .po files for the relevant strings:

> The locale module allows you to
>   present your Drupal site in a language
>   other than the default English. You
>   can use it to set up a multi-lingual
>   web site or replace given built-in
>   text with text which has been
>   customized for your site. Whenever the
>   locale module encounters text which
>   needs to be displayed, it tries to
>   translate it into the currently
>   selected language. If a translation is
>   not available, then the string is
>   remembered, so you can look up
>   untranslated strings easily.
>
> The locale module provides two options for providing translations.
>   The first is the integrated web
>   interface, via which you can search
>   for untranslated strings, and specify
>   their translations. An easier and less
>   time-consuming method is to import
>   existing translations for your
>   language. These translations are
>   available as GNU gettext Portable
>   Object files (.po files for short).
>   Translations for many languages are
>   available for download from the
>   translation page.

Comment: Well times not much of an issue I have my own partial cmses already which I've built but I haven't worked with bi lingual websites. Just want to know that in bi lingual websites how are the different pages handled? In both languages?

Comment: yep, drupal is far the worst solution for this problem, i think.

Comment: fabrik, not sure about that. But any handrolled CMS is surely worse than that, just think about the changes you have to made when requirement changes.

Comment: ok, this is not the best place to talk about this but i think drupal is the most bloated software on the market. the task is simple: given 10 (mostly) static pages in two different languages. imho the best solution for this is exactly a handrolled CMS like you said. what is the point in drupal at this situation? maintainability? why not wordpress? i admit that i doesn't know drupal totally in-depth but this articles gave me some insight for this monster: http://robozen.com/technology/drupal-sucks/ i'd like to know this post was a joke but it isn't i think.